# Visual C++: Using nested templates, is it possible to mark ">>" instead of "> >" as error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Is it possible to mark ">>" instead of "> >" as error in Visual Studio when using nested templates?

Example code:

```
void foo(std::vector<std::vector<double>>) {}
```

The Visual C++ compiler (I'm using VS10/2010) does not complain even on warning level 4, but building on Unix and Linux compilers fails with error ([ideone](http://ideone.com/bp4VkB)):

```
error: '>>' should be '> >' within a nested template argument list
```

**Is it possible to mark this as an error?**

I want to make sure that my code is free of this trivial syntax errors before sending it to the CI server as much as possible...

Comment: Do you have control over the command-line options used on the CI server? `>>` is perfectly valid as of C++11, and current versions of GCC will accept it if you pass `-std=c++11` (or `-std=gnu++11`, `-std=c++1y`, `-std=gnu++1y`, whichever is most appropriate for you) on the command-line.

Comment: It is not an error in C++11, see http://ideone.com/ossbOr

Comment: Good idea, i wasn't aware of this - I'll check ;)

Comment: set your linux compiler to C++11 e.g. with g++ `-std=c++11`

Comment: It kinda bothers me we have to explicitly tell g++ to use the latest standard of C++...but well, we do.

Comment: @CrazyEddie That's probably because the support for C++11 is not complete, or that the authors don't consider it fully robust.

Comment: One Of Compiler versions is too old... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 made `>>` to end nested templates legal. The issue is that VC++ 2010 implements (and enables unconditionally) this part of C++11, but you're using other compilers which either don't implement this in the version you're targeting or you haven't enabled their C++11 mode.

VC++ doesn't support modes and instead simply enables bits and pieces of language specs as they get around to implementing them. So your solution is to either downgrade the VC++ compiler to a version that doesn't enable this feature, or upgrade or enable C++11 on the other compilers you're targeting so that this is not an error.

---

If you can't do either of those, and if you're not already using an automated build system then you can set one up to help catch these compatibilities errors faster than you currently are. Configure one so that as soon as any team member commits new code the code is checked on all the platforms you support.

Automated build systems often also allow users to provide code changes to be checked on all the build slaves directly from the team member's working directory, instead of requiring the code to be committed to the shared repo first. Setting this up is just about as good as having the initial development occur directly on each supported platform.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is an error using GCC 4.8.1 and not with Visual Studio 2010 (MSVC10) is that the former defaults to not using C++11 and the latter defaults to using it. Being able to use `>>` in a nested template list is a C++11 feature. To use C++11 features with GCC and Clang you need to pass in the `-std=C++11` flag as a minimum to the compiler.

As for showing this within Visual Studio using intellisense I do not believe this is possible as it is not possible to tell MSVC to compile to different ISO standards.